# Argument name in a macro in another

Tags: macros, hyperref

I want to define a macro (I've simplifyed for posting a clean code) in a macro which name's depend on the name of an argument of the first macro. Here I use the packages `amsthm`, `hyperref` and `aliascnt`, but I suppose it does not matter for answering.

I want it executes the code : `\providecommand*{\MyFirstautorefname}{MySecond}`
when I call `\mymacro{Myfist}{MySecond}` in the preamble.
I know it may be the easiest thing for Kings in LaTeX, but I didn't find how to do it ... I tried this code :

```
    \newcommand{\mymacro}[2]{
       \providecommand*{\#1autorefname}{#2}
    }
```

and the same with `\csname#1\endcsname` but there is "autorefname" to concatene.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  \newcommand{\mymacro}[2]{%%
       \expandafter\providecommand\expandafter
              *\csname#1autorefname\endcsname{#2}%%
    }
```

then if `#1` is `zzz` `\zzzautorefname` will be defined.

Comment: Thanks !!!! You're the best ! And the answer in less than a minute !! Awesome !!!

Comment: I presume you need that second `\expandafter` to jump over the `*`?

Comment: @SeanAllred yes

Answer (score 2):

Also, the LaTeX kernel provides `\@namedef` for this:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\mymacro}[2]{%
  \@namedef{#1autorefname}{#2}%
}
\maketatother
```

Indeed, the task you want to accomplish is a pretty common one: just think of how labels for cross-referencing are defined.

**Caveat:** In contrast with the `\providecommand` solution, `\@namedef` will silently overwrite a previous definition of a command with the same name; this can be prevented with

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\mymacro}[2]{%
  \@ifundefined{#1autorefname}{%
    \@namedef{#1autorefname}{#2}%
  }{%
    \typeout{`#1autorefname' is already defined.}%
  }
}
\maketatother
```

or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

An `expl3` way to do this could be:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \mathfortyfive_maybe_define:Nn #1#2
  { \cs_if_free:NT #1 { \cs_new_nopar:Npn #1 {#2} } }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \mathfortyfive_maybe_define:Nn { cn }

\NewDocumentCommand \mymacro { mm }
  { \mathfortyfive_maybe_define:cn { #1 autorefname } { #2 } }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

There may be functions I'm not aware of though; I'm not at my normal computer with access to all my TeX tools `:)` As such, it should go without saying that this is as-yet untested.

Comment: @egreg But if it's defined it stops there with an error, and we want “`\providecommand`”.

Comment: @egreg You're right that it does the check, but I see your point about putting the definition of `\mathfortyfive_maybe_define:Nn` straight into the document-level command. I guess I just don't feel right doing anything but input parsing in document-level commands :P It makes some things more verbose, but I personally like the absolute structure that restriction provides.