# Testing whether a name is defined after building up the name

Tags: conditionals

I'd like to test whether `\solflag` is defined or whether `\profflag` is defined. I'd like to do so with a macro whose argument could be either "sol" or "prof" (or some other word).

My "minimal (non)working example" attempt at this is

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\newcommand{\solflag}{}
\newcommand{\mytest}[1]
   {\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\#1flag}} {UNDEFINED}{DEFINED}}

\begin{document}

Sol test: \mytest{sol}

Bar test: \mytest{bar}

2nd bar test: \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\barflag}} {UNDEFINED}{DEFINED}

\end{document}
```

The result, however, is this:

```
Sol test: DEFINED
Bar test: DEFINED
2nd bar test: UNDEFINED
```

My guess is that the first "Bar" test is checking whether `\bar` is defined, i.e., that the concatenation of `\#1` and `flag` in the macro just isn't happening or something.

I suspect that the answer I need is somewhere in the LaTeX-Fu of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247071/argument-name-in-a-macro-in-another), but I simply cannot make head or tail of that.

Is it possible to do what I'm hoping to do?

Comment: your `\mytest` douesn't use `#1` at all so it does not use its argument

Comment: @DavidCarlisle He actually *does* use `#1`, but with the improper syntax `\#1flag`.  To the OP, the proper way to convey `\#1flag` is `\csname #1flag\endcsname`.  The sequence `\#1flag` gets expanded as `#1flag` where `#` is literally the pound sign.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes no, that was my point `#1` would be a reference to an argument `\#` is an instruction to typeset a `#` (a pound sign is £ :-) it does not _expand_ to a `#` (it doesn't expand at all actually, it's a chardef token)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, I see your point.  It is just that your initial comment was a bit cryptic for one who might have otherwise thought that `\#1flag` would work.

Comment: cryptic is good sometimes:-)

Comment: I'd like to thank all the folks who answered; each answer taught me something new. (And @DavidCarlisle's comment taught me to beware of his answer, because they might be more subtle than they seem...)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `#`=American "pound". I'm so...'80's.  What do the youngsters call it now??? "Hashtag"! "HASHTAG!!"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `etoolbox` package has a lot of good stuff in it for these and other low level things.

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\solflag}{}
\newcommand{\mytest}[1]{\ifcsdef{#1flag}{DEFINED}{UNDEFINED}}
\begin{document}
Sol test: \mytest{sol}

Bar test: \mytest{bar}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Other similar tests provided by the package include `\ifdef`, `\ifundef`, `\ifcsundef`, `\ifdefmacro`, `\ifcsmacro` and many more.

Answer (score 2):

When you write

```
\#1flag
```

you have six tokens

```
\# • 1 • f • l • a • g
```

(I use `•` for separating tokens by ease of reading). You may be better served with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand{\solflag}{}
\newcommand{\mytest}[1]{%
  \ifthenelse{\expandafter\isundefined\expandafter{\csname #1flag\endcsname}}
    {UNDEFINED}{DEFINED}% 
}

\begin{document}

Sol test: \mytest{sol}

Bar test: \mytest{bar}

2nd bar test: \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\barflag}} {UNDEFINED}{DEFINED}

\end{document}
```

that prepares the token `\barflag` before being evaluated by `\ifthenelse`.

[image]

The LaTeX kernel has already a macro for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand{\solflag}{}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mytest}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{#1flag}{UNDEFINED}{DEFINED}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Sol test: \mytest{sol}

Bar test: \mytest{bar}

2nd bar test: \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\barflag}} {UNDEFINED}{DEFINED}

\end{document}
```

However, this has the consequence that the following test based on `\isundefined` returns true.

If you plan to use both kinds of test, use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand{\solflag}{}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mytest}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \@ifundefined{#1flag}{\endgroup\@firstoftwo}{\endgroup\@secondoftwo}%
  {UNDEFINED}%
  {DEFINED}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Sol test: \mytest{sol}

Bar test: \mytest{bar}

2nd bar test: \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\barflag}} {UNDEFINED}{DEFINED}

\end{document}
```

On a modern TeX system, LaTeX uses e-TeX, so you can do

```
\newcommand{\mytest}[1]{%
  \ifcsname #1flag\endcsname
    DEFINED%
  \else
    UNDEFINED%
  \fi
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use `ifthen` for this, but if you do then you need to use `#1` to construct the csname to test. Note `\#` is a command to produce `#` it is not a reference to an argument, so your definition does not use its argument at all.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}


\newcommand{\solflag}{}
\newcommand{\mytest}[1]{%
  \ifthenelse{\expandafter\isundefined\csname#1flag\endcsname}{UNDEFINED}{DEFINED}}

\begin{document}

Sol test: \mytest{sol}

Bar test: \mytest{bar}

2nd bar test: \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\barflag}} {UNDEFINED}{DEFINED}

\end{document}
```